# R command with same operation by countifs() formula in excel

Tags: r

is there any command in R language with the same operation with Countifs() formula in excel?

Comment: `sum(variable == "value")`

Comment: It is considered polite to upvote and accept any responses that solved your question or you found useful.

Comment: thank you.what can i do that in a data.frame?

Answer (score 0):

In R, if you have a vector:

```
vector <- c(rep(4,3), rep(3,3))
```

you can say, for example:

```
vector == 4
```

which will give you the following output:

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

so, sinces TRUE values equals 1 under the hood, then you can say

```
sum(vector == 4)
```

output:

```
[1] 3
```

which is like countif values of vector are equals to 4

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```
# If you want the total count:  
ave(df$group_vector, df$group_vector, FUN = length)

# If you want a sequential count as in `COUNTIFS($A$1:$A1, $A1)`
ave(df$group_vector, df$group_vector, FUN = seq.int)
```